# Update model db schema in keystone.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I have created a new model 'Product.js' in keystone.js at shown.

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Product = new keystone.List('Product', {
    map: {name: 'title'},
    singular: 'Product',
    plural: 'Products',
    autokey: {path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true}
});

Product.add({
    title: {type: String, required: true}, 
    price: {type: Number},
    qty: { type: Number },
    description: {type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 300},
    image: {type: Types.CloudinaryImage},
    publishedDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

Product.register();
```

I see these attributes at admin UI. Now I want to update it and add a new attribute dynamically (without changing any thing in this file). In routing file product.js, I am able to create new instance (following [this](https://gist.github.com/JedWatson/10739959) article) to fill existing attributes like this.

```
keystone.createItems({
    Product: [{
        title: 'Product 3',
        price: 34,
        qty: 4,
        description: "sldfkjslkfjlskdjfsdfj",       
        __ref: 'prod'
    }]
}, function (err, stats) {
    stats && console.log(stats.message);
});
```

Is there any function like this available to change Product schema?

I want to add a new attribute in this model in mongoose db. How can I do it? And where does keystone.js store db file in windows?

Answer (score 1):

Schema are not meant to be modified at runtime, especially the way they are leveraged in Keystone to generate the Admin UI.

Here is an interesting article about using Mongo without a schema: [MongoDB: To Use Schemas or Not?](https://www.compose.com/articles/mongodb-with-and-without-schemas/)

Here is the mongoose team's take on a similar question: [Dynamically adding fields in the schema doesn't permit to add fields as usual](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1867)

If you are going 'schemaless' or using [Mixed Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed), Keystone might not be the platform you want to use, as it requires schema to be defined at build-time by design.